# How can I create multiple objects using an array of arrays using D3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

**How can I create multiple objects using an array of arrays using D3?**

1. I am trying to create an application where I have a JSON that contains four objects representing four different school courses, and each object contains an array with an object representing the subjects included in that course.
2. I am stuck because I create four nodes of the "node" class representing each course, and I save the array of subjects in their data. However, I have no idea how to create new objects based on the data from the "node" class.

[image]

3. If I now wanted to insert multiple circles based on each object stored in the dataset array of each node, how could I do it?

`const clases = enterNodes.selectAll("asignatura").data(data.map(d => d.asignaturas));`

I have tried to create a selection where I create a circle and bind it to the subjects dataset. The problem is that this approach is not giving me the desired result, as I want to use the dataset already stored in the node.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please use code blocks instead of images. All questions are answered by unpaid volunteers, most of whom do not have the time to manually type code from an image. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

First, sharing your code would make it easier to help.

There are a few questions to make that are crucial to be able to help you.

What are the course nodes you just created?
Do you need to group these subject circles? Or can you mix them together?

One error in the code you shared is that unless you have a custom HTML tag named "asignatura", `.selectAll("asignatura")` won't work, "asignatura" is an invalid selector.